# How to modify entry in database in appengine?

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine

Want to edit datatabase. I have tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
    def post(self, pageName):$
        content = self.request.get('content')$
$
        p = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Pages")$
        pages = p.run(batch_size = 1000)$
        pageExist = False$
$
        for page in pages:$
            if pageName == page.name:$
                page.content = content$
                break$
            else:$
                p = Pages(name = pageName, content = content)$
                p.put()$
        self.redirect(pageName)$
```

Need some code help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you find `pageName` and change the `content` on the corresponding page, you'll need to save page before redirecting.

And if the intent is to update a page with new `content`, I'm not at all sure what you're trying to accomplish with that `else:` block.

I think you'll be happier doing something like

```
query = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Pages WHERE pageName=:1", pageName)
for page in query:
  page.content = content
  page.put()
```

Comment: Else block ads new row to the schema. Could you please provide me a code to save it?

Comment: Misread the else block. Code added above. Basically, you're missing a `put()`.

Comment: Also, by not filtering on `pageName`, you're going to end up creating an ever-growing number of duplicate `Pages`. Assuming you don't want duplicates, consider using `pageName` as the name of the Key.